# Differentiate $y=2(\ln x)^ \frac x2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I tried doing the chain-rule but when I compared my answers to my TI-nspire and Wolfram I was missing a whole section. I have no idea how to differentiate $f(x)^{g(x)}$.

Comment: Taking logs of both sides and using [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) would seem to be the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f^g$ can be written as $e^{g \log f}$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}
= 2 \frac{d}{dx} (\log x)^{x/2}
&= 2 \frac{d}{dx} e^{\log \log x \cdot x/2} \\
&= 2 e^{\log \log x \cdot x/2} \frac{d}{dx} (\log \log x \cdot x/2) \\
&= 2 (\log x)^{x/2} \left( \log \log x \frac{d(x/2)}{dx} + \frac{x}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \log \log x\right) \\
&= 2 (\log x)^{x/2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \log \log x + \frac{x}{2} \frac{\log' x}{\log x}\right) \\
&= (\log x)^{x/2} \left( \log \log x + x \frac{1/x}{\log x}\right) \\
&= (\log x)^{x/2} \left( \log \log x + \frac{1}{\log x}\right) \\
\end{align*}$$
I used the formula for [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative).

Answer (score 1):

For the most general case, consider $$y=f(x)^{g(x)}$$ and take logarithms. So $$\log(y)=g(x)\log(f(x))$$ Differentiating both sides and  using the product rule for the rhs leads to $$\frac{y'}y=g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+g'(x)\log(f(x))$$ Then $$y'=f(x)^{g(x)} \left(\frac{g(x) f'(x)}{f(x)}+\log (f(x)) g'(x)\right)$$